# React Router Props of parent component refresh whenever I switch between children components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create simple social media app using React, where users would post something and everyone else would see posts on feed.
I have a Home component, to whom I pass props through login component using useHistory.push method.
In Home component I want NavBar to be persistent and to switch content using NavBar links. Whenever I change child component using Route and Link, Home component reloads and loses props, leading to 'cant read property username of undefined' error.
In props I only keep username of logged person.

App component (default)

```
function App() {
  console.log('app loaded')
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
        <Route path="/app" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home component

```
const Home = (props) => {
    console.log('loaded home')
    const username = props.location.state.username

    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar user={username} />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/app/feed" component={Feed} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

NavBar component

```
const NavBar = (props) => {
    return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">
                <h2>Welcome, {props.user}</h2>
                <ul className="navbar-nav">
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/app/feed" className="nav-link">Feed</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/app" className="nav-link">User Page</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/" className="nav-link" id="log-out-link">Log out</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
    )
}
export default NavBar;
```

I've just begun using React, so if I need different approach I'd be grateful to read some advices.

Comment: As soon as the path changes, so too does `location`; `props.location` will be the location object of the new route/matched path. Perhaps you should store the authenticated state/person in `App` and pass as a prop to the routed components, or use something like the react Context API or similar (i.e. redux).

Comment: Thank you very much! I from login page I passed props to Home component using useState hook, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I would rewrite your code like this:

App.js

```
function App() {
  console.log('app loaded')
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
      <Route path="/app" component={Home}>
        <Route path="/app/feed" component={Feed} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
const Home = (props) => {
console.log('loaded home')
const username = props.location.state.username

return (
    <div>
        <NavBar user={username} />
    </div>
)
}

export default Home;
```

NavBar.js

```
const NavBar = (props) => {
return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">
            <h2>Welcome, {props.user}</h2>
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
                <li className="nav-item" onClick={() => history.push('/app/feed') }>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item" onClick={() => history.push('/app') }>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item" onClick={() => history.push('/')>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
)
}
export default NavBar;
```

This implementation should solve your problem.